# Fetching emails after a given UID via PHP imap_search

Tags: php, email, imap, php-imap

I store a local copy of my Gmail inbox via PHP IMAP. I need to fetch any emails which had not been fetched before. This is possible by `date` as

```
imap_search($imap, 'SINCE "15 April 2022"');
```

but, I look for a possibility to fetch all emails with the condition of `UID>x` where `x` is the `UID` of the last email fetched since working with a unique ID is easier than `date`.

Comment: 'UID SEARCH UID n:*' where n is 1 more than x, and you filter out the x if there are no new messages.

Comment: First search with UID, then search with SINCE.